# how to download multiple files from URL in FlatList in react native with separate progress bar

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs

i am new in `react-native` and I want download multiple data in `FlatList` using `URL` with `progress bar` separate for its item download process ...in single file its process and progress working fine but when I try to download multiple file that time its not working.
download multyple files hangs full mobile screen and not able to use any other options from screen

how to do download from URL and display percentage in list

[image]

```
 const DATA = [
{
  id: '0',
  file_title: 'zero Item',
  download_file_url: 'http://212.183.159.230/50MB.zip',
},
{
  id: '1',
  file_title: 'First Item',
  download_file_url: 'http://212.183.159.230/50MB.zip',
},]


 <FlatList
      data={DATA}
      horizontal={false}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />


  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
     <Item title={item.file_title} downloadUrl={item.download_file_url} />
 );

const Item = ({title, downloadUrl}) => (
  <View>
    <DownloadItem title={title} downloadUrl={downloadUrl} />
  </View>
);
```

i also declare seprate component for download

```
const DownloadItem = ({title, downloadUrl}) => {
const [downloadProgress, setDownloadProgress] = useState(0);
 return (
  <View>
  <View style={style.parentView}>
    <View
      style={{
        height: 55,
        width: 55,
        borderRadius: 2,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: rendomRGB(),
      }}>
      <Text style={style.extensionTxt}>
        {getFirstCharacterOfExtensionFromURL(downloadUrl)}
      </Text>
    </View>

    <View>
      <Text style={style.fileTitle}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={style.fileDesc}>{title}</Text>
      <View style={style.progressView}>
        <Progress.Bar
          style={style.fileDesc}
          progress={downloadProgress}
          width={200}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => startDownloadZip(title, downloadUrl)}>
          <Image
            style={style.imgCloseResume}
            source={require('../../assets/close.png')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>

  <View style={style.deviderView}></View>
</View>
);



function startDownloadZip(title, downloadUrl) {
const appParentPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath; 
const appFolderPath = appParentPath + '/MyFiles';

RNFS.mkdir(appFolderPath)
  .then(success => {
    console.log('Folder created!', success);
    background: true,
    RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: `${downloadUrl}`,
      toFile: `${appFolderPath + '/' + title}`,
      progress: (res: DownloadProgressCallbackResult) => {

        let progressPercent = res.bytesWritten / res.contentLength; // to calculate in percentage
        setDownloadProgress(progressPercent);
      },
    })
      .promise.then(responce => {
        console.log('file download ', responce);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('download error', err);
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('mkdir error ', err);
  });
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a standalone component for your `renderItem` in which you can call the download progress. I attach an example below.

```
function ParentComp() {


  return <FlatList renderItem={({item}) => <ChildComponent item={item} />} />
}
```

```
function ChildComponent({item}) {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)

  "here comes your RNFS logic"

  return <ProgressBar value={progress} />
}
```

Comment: yes I done same way...I return whole view...I update my answer

Comment: @BiRjU ok I see you have done the pattern that I suggested. So your problem is that the progress bar doesn't work, right?

Comment: progressbar is working...but after 2-3 item start downloding i face problame to bottom tab change and scroll ...like its hang whole screen

Comment: Is your flatlist in a modal?

Comment: No its in stack of navigation

Comment: FlastList has an in-built lazy load feature it can cause your issue. First I would try with a simple `map`.

Comment: @BiRjU I am getting same issue. Could you share you solution code if you done this.